# Cannot prove equivalence with a path dependent type

Tags: scala, dependent-type, scala-3, path-dependent-type

Why does the last `summon` fails to compile? What can I do to make it compile?

```
import java.time.{LocalDateTime, LocalTime}

trait Circular[T]:
  type Parent

given localTimeCircular: Circular[LocalTime] with
  type Parent = LocalDateTime

final class CircularMap[K, +V]()(using val circular: Circular[K])

val summoned = summon[Circular[LocalTime]]
val daily = new CircularMap[LocalTime, Int]()
println(summoned == daily.circular) // Prints true

summon[localTimeCircular.Parent =:= LocalDateTime]
summon[summoned.Parent =:= LocalDateTime]

summon[daily.circular.Parent =:= LocalDateTime]
```

[Scastie link](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/kPpc3L2xRxKrRcOy3QBvFg)

It fails on Scala 3.0.2 and 3.1.0-RC1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The thing is not in Scala 3. In Scala 2.13.6 simlar code doesn't compile

```
import shapeless.the

import java.time.{LocalDateTime, LocalTime}

trait Circular[T] {
  type Parent
}

implicit object localTimeCircular extends Circular[LocalTime] {
  type Parent = LocalDateTime
}
//  implicit val localTimeCircular: Circular[LocalTime] {type Parent = LocalDateTime} = new Circular[LocalTime] {
//    type Parent = LocalDateTime
//  }

final class CircularMap[K, +V]()(implicit val circular: Circular[K])

val summoned = the[Circular[LocalTime]]
val daily = new CircularMap[LocalTime, Int]()
println(summoned == daily.circular) // Prints true

implicitly[localTimeCircular.Parent =:= LocalDateTime]
implicitly[summoned.Parent =:= LocalDateTime]

//implicitly[daily.circular.Parent =:= LocalDateTime] // doesn't compile
```

https://scastie.scala-lang.org/DmytroMitin/lsX3fS3ET0ajzChwl2Mctw

(I replaced `implicitly` with `the` in one place because `implicitly` can break type refinements, `summon` is more like `the`).

Let's simplify your code in order to figure out what's going on. Let's remove implicits (let's resolve them explicitly)

```
import java.time.{LocalDateTime, LocalTime}

trait Circular[T] {
  type Parent
}

val localTimeCircular = new Circular[LocalTime] {
  type Parent = LocalDateTime
}

final class CircularMap[K, +V](val circular: Circular[K])

val summoned = localTimeCircular
val daily = new CircularMap[LocalTime, Int](localTimeCircular)
println(summoned == daily.circular) // Prints true

implicitly[localTimeCircular.Parent =:= LocalDateTime]
implicitly[summoned.Parent =:= LocalDateTime]

//implicitly[daily.circular.Parent =:= LocalDateTime] // doesn't compile
```

The thing is that path-dependent types are designed so that even if `x == x1` it's not necessary that `x.T =:= x1.T`

[In the latest release of scala (2.12.x), is the implementation of path-dependent type incomplete?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62236708/in-the-latest-release-of-scala-2-12-x-is-the-implementation-of-path-dependent)

[Force dependent types resolution for implicit calls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56836087/force-dependent-types-resolution-for-implicit-calls/)

[How to create an instances for typeclass with dependent type using shapeless](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61044126/how-to-create-an-instances-for-typeclass-with-dependent-type-using-shapeless)

It's true that `summoned == daily.circular` but `summoned` has type `Circular[LocalTime] { type Parent = LocalDateTime }` while `daily.circular` has type `Circular[LocalTime]`. You specified it so: `val circular: Circular[K]`. So you upcasted refined type `Circular[LocalTime] { type Parent = LocalDateTime }` (let's denote it `Circular.Aux[LocalTime, LocalDateTime]`) to its supertype, namely the type without refinement `Circular[LocalTime]` (aka existential type `Circular.Aux[LocalTime, _]`). So types `localTimeCircular.Parent` and `summoned.Parent` are `LocalDateTime` but type `daily.circular.Parent` is abstract. If you want to restore type refinement for example you can define

```
final class CircularMap[K, +V, P](val circular: Circular[K] {type Parent = P})
```

Another way is to use singleton type

```
final class CircularMap[K, +V](val circular: localTimeCircular.type)
```

---

> Is there a way to not lose the refinement `Circular[LocalTime] { type Parent = LocalDateTime }` without introducing the type parameter `P` on
> the class `CircularMap`? Something like
> `final class CircularMap[K, +V](val circular: Circular[K] { type Parent = X })` where `X` would introduce a new type variable in the scope of the `CircularMap` body.

What you want is actually multiple type parameter lists on class (so that in `class CircularMap[K, +V][P]` you can specify `K`, `V` and infer `P`)

https://github.com/scala/bug/issues/4719

https://contributors.scala-lang.org/t/multiple-type-parameter-lists-in-dotty-si-4719/2399

You can emulate them

```
import java.time.{LocalDateTime, LocalTime}

trait Circular[T] {
  type Parent
}

val localTimeCircular = new Circular[LocalTime] {
  type Parent = LocalDateTime
}

trait CircularMap[K, +V] {
  type P
  val circular: Circular[K] {type Parent = P}
}
object CircularMap {
  def apply[K, V]: PartiallyApplied[K, V] = new PartiallyApplied[K, V]

  class PartiallyApplied[K, V] {
    def apply[_P](_circular: Circular[K] {type Parent = _P}): CircularMap[K, V] {type P = _P} = new CircularMap[K, V] {
      override type P = _P
      override val circular: Circular[K] {type Parent = _P} = _circular
    }
  }
}

val summoned = localTimeCircular
val daily = CircularMap[LocalTime, Int](localTimeCircular)
println(summoned == daily.circular) // Prints true

implicitly[localTimeCircular.Parent =:= LocalDateTime]
implicitly[summoned.Parent =:= LocalDateTime]
implicitly[daily.circular.Parent =:= LocalDateTime] // compiles
```

Comment: Is there a way to not lose the refinement `Circular[LocalTime] { type Parent = LocalDateTime }` without introducing the type parameter `P` on the class `CircularMap`?

Comment: Something like `final class CircularMap[K, +V](val circular: Circular[K] { type Parent = X })` where `X` would introduce a new type variable in the scope of the CircularMap body.