# Scala 3: dealing with path dependent types

Tags: scala, scala-3, path-dependent-type

Consider the following snippet:

```scala
object Test extends App {
  class X {
    class Y
  }

  class Z(val x: X) {
    val y: x.Y = new x.Y
  }

  val x: X = new X
  val z: Z = new Z(x)
  val y: x.Y = z.y

  println(y)
}
```

This code won't compile, complaing about incompatible path-dependent types:

```
[error] 12 |  val y: x.Y = z.y
[error]    |               ^^^
[error]    |               Found:    (Test.z.y : Test.z.x.Y)
[error]    |               Required: Test.x².Y
[error]    |
[error]    |               where:    x  is a value in class Z
[error]    |                         x² is a value in object Test
[error]    |
```

Is there a way to gently remind the compiler that `z.x` is assigned to `x` just one line above?

Even `if (z.x == x) { val y: x.Y = z.y }` does not solve the issue, even though path equivalence should be inferred from control flow.

**Background:** Scala 3 macro API heavily uses PDT's, and this creates **huge** amount of pain to deal with --- all this pain is coming from compiler's inability to infer anything, and lack of syntactic structures to explicitly control that inference.

Comment: If you remove the explicit type annotations does it work?

Answer (score 4):

This is correct behavior for path-dependent types (by the way, in Scala 2 it's the same).

Would you be satisfied with

```
val y: z.x.Y = z.y // compiles
```

?

`z.x` equals `x` but this doesn't mean that the type `z.x.Y` is `x.Y`.

Similarly,

```
class A {
  type T
}
val a = new A
val a1 = a
//implicitly[a.T =:= a1.T] // doesn't compile
```

`a` equals to `a1` but this doesn't mean that the type `a.T` is `a1.T`.

This is Scala 2 spec for equivalence of path-dependent types: https://scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.13/03-types.html#equivalence.
In our case the prefixes have different singleton types:

```
implicitly[z.x.type =:= x.type] // doesn't compile
```

> - If a path `p` has a singleton type `q.type`, then `p.type ≡ q.type`.
> - If `O` is defined by an object definition, and `p` is a path
>   consisting only of package or object selectors and ending in `O`, then
>   `O.this.type ≡ p.type`.

You can fix the compilation:

```
class A {
  type T
}
val a = new A
val a1: a.type = a
implicitly[a.T =:= a1.T] // compiles
```

and

```
class X {
  class Y
}

class Z(val x: X) {
  type V = x.Y // added
  val y: V = new x.Y
}

val x: X = new X
val z: Z = new Z(x)
val y: z.V = z.y // compiles
```

See also:

[In the latest release of scala (2.12.x), is the implementation of path-dependent type incomplete?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62236708/in-the-latest-release-of-scala-2-12-x-is-the-implementation-of-path-dependent)

[Cannot prove equivalence with a path dependent type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69120836/cannot-prove-equivalence-with-a-path-dependent-type)

[Force dependent types resolution for implicit calls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56836087/force-dependent-types-resolution-for-implicit-calls)

[How to help the Scala 3 compiler infer a path-dependent-type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69313710/how-to-help-the-scala-3-compiler-infer-a-path-dependent-type)

[How to create an instances for typeclass with dependent type using shapeless](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61044126/how-to-create-an-instances-for-typeclass-with-dependent-type-using-shapeless)

If you use REPL you'll see the types inferred  by the compiler (removing explicit type annotations as **@LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez** advised in comments):

```
scala> class X {
     |   class Y
     | }
class X

scala> class Z(val x: X) {
     |   val y: x.Y = new x.Y
     | }
class Z

scala> val x = new X
val x: X = X@6f76c2cc

scala> val z = new Z(x)
val z: Z = Z@7e62cfa3

scala> val y = z.y
val y: z.x.Y = X$Y@52bd9a27  // notice z.x, not x
```

Comment: Well, so there is no way to make this work. I cannot stick to same prefix everywhere. This simplified snippet represents the situation when I _have_ to pass the PDT to different class, and have it interoperable with outside code.

It's sad that Scala has so incomplete implementation of the feature, and it's a pity that such incomplete feature is used in macros, making large macros rather difficult to write without tons of casts.

Comment: @Maxim This is not incomplete implementation, this is intended behavior. I can't see how this can be implemented differently. Equality `a == a1` is checked at runtime (you can override `equals`). Even referential equality `a eq a1` is checked at runtime (you need JVM for that, not only Scala compiler). Types are inferred at compile time, so `a.T =:= a1.T` is checked at compile time when we can't know yet whether `a` and `a1` are the same. Maybe you should open a new question with your actual use case (macros) and we'll see if we could handle your issues more optimally.

Comment: It is incomplete not w.r.t. specification, but w.r.t. use cases. Compiler _could_ prove statically that two paths refers to same instance. Ok, not `==`, and not even `eq`. `val x` in `Z` is a stable identifier, it's initialized with `x`, and to best of my knowledge this should imply that `z.x` and `x` are _statically_ equivalent.

Comment: @Maxim Thanks for clarification of your point. Then I guess you'd like singleton types `z.x.type`, `x.type` to be the same too. I still think it's better to discuss this on your actual use case.

Comment: @Maxim Scala 3 macros are already easier in this sense than Scala 2 macros. Compare signatures `inline def macroImpl[T](x: Expr[T])(using Quotes, Type[T]): Expr[T]` vs. `def macroImpl[T: c.WeakTypeTag](c: blackbox.Context)(x: c.Expr[T]): c.Expr[T]`. `Expr`, `Type` do not depend on context.

Comment: @Maxim It's possible that you can avoid casting if you introduce a generic `def foo[Q <: Quotes]` and use it like `foo[q.type]`.

Comment: @Maxim See how path-dependent types were handled in Scala 2 macros https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/macros/overview.html#writing-bigger-macros (even before macro bundles).

Comment: @Maxim Also https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/quasiquotes/lifting.html#reusing-liftable-implementation-between-universes