In Scala 3 with DOT calculus, how to extend the equality of 2 path dependent types for obviously cases?
Considering the following example in an Object:
  object Assuming {

    trait Foo {

      type S1
    }

    object Obj1 {

      val v: Foo = ???
      val v1 = v
      val v2 = v

      implicitly[v.S1 =:= v.S1]

      // all the following failed
      implicitly[v.S1 =:= v1.S1]
      implicitly[v1.S1 =:= v2.S1]

      def fn1(v: Foo): Unit = {
        val v1 = v
        val v2 = v

        implicitly[v1.S1 =:= v2.S1]
      }
    }
  }

The 3 failures are:

[Error] E:/peng/git/dottyspike/src/main/scala/com/tribbloids/spike/dotty/DependentEquality.scala:66:33: Cannot prove that com.tribbloids.spike.dotty.DependentEquality.Assuming.Obj1.v.S1 =:= com.tribbloids.spike.dotty.DependentEquality.Assuming.Obj1.v1.S1.
[Error] E:/peng/git/dottyspike/src/main/scala/com/tribbloids/spike/dotty/DependentEquality.scala:67:34: Cannot prove that com.tribbloids.spike.dotty.DependentEquality.Assuming.Obj1.v1.S1 =:= com.tribbloids.spike.dotty.DependentEquality.Assuming.Obj1.v2.S1.
[Error] E:/peng/git/dottyspike/src/main/scala/com/tribbloids/spike/dotty/DependentEquality.scala:73:36: Cannot prove that v1.S1 =:= v2.S1.

This is obviously wrong, as v, v1, v2 obviously has the same reference within their context. In addition, the outcome won't change if some or all of the v, v1, v2 are changed to def or lazy val.
My questions are:

What's the root cause of this? I know v1/v2/v have different paths, but if compiletime ops is used (https://docs.scala-lang.org/scala3/reference/metaprogramming/compiletime-ops.html), 1+1 and 2 also have different paths, yet compiler is able to resolve it successfully

If I want to extend this behaviour, by manually introducing an assumption/axiom that v/v1/v2 are the same thing, which can work in the above cases. I would also like to carry this contextual assumption to else where, such that I can write things like:


     def fn1(v1: Foo, v2: Foo)(using v1.type =!= v2.type): Unit = {

        implicitly[v1.S1 =:= v2.S1]
     }

OR
     def fn1(v1: Foo, v2: Foo)(using Congruent[v1.type, v2.type]): Unit = {

        implicitly[v1.S1 =:= v2.S1]
     }

How do I define it? I'm OK with solution using any Scala 3 feature, but metaprogramming solutions may be accepted slower than usual.
UPDATE 1 Thanks to @Mateusz I was able to determine the root cause, and it is widening type inference (a source of many complaint & SIP, e.g. https://github.com/scala/scala3/issues/3920#issuecomment-360779916)
In short, the type of v1 & v2 are Foo, not dependent at all. I have to define their types explicitly to make the compiler work:


  object Assuming {

    trait Foo {

      type S1
    }

    object Obj1 {

      val v: Foo = ???
      val v1: v.type = v
      val v2: v1.type = v1

      summon[v.S1 =:= v.S1]
//      summon[Eq[v.S1, v.S1]]

      // all the following failed
      summon[v.S1 =:= v1.S1]
      summon[v1.S1 =:= v2.S1]

      def fn1(v: Foo): Unit = {
        val v1: v.type = v
        val v2: v1.type = v1

        summon[v1.S1 =:= v2.S1]
      }
    }
  }

This answered the first question, so I'm only looking for the second answer now.

I think compiletime ops only work because: it uses transparent inline def, so compiler see exactly each type where compiletime ops is used, and it operate on singleton-based literals which get a special treatment. When you replace your vals with transparent inline def it works.

thanks a lot, this answered the first question (tho theoretically objects should be singletons)

Obj1 is singleton, v1/v2 are not, so there is nothing that compiler can prove about them other than there is some v.type, v1.type and v2.type and that they are not the same val.

Other way to put it: when you use enum Foo { case Bar, Baz } it will be translated into sealed trait Foo; object Foo { val Bar = new Foo{}; val Baz = new Foo {} } - 2 vals with anonymous classes instead of objects. Pattern matching can distinguish them only because Foo.Bar.type is different than Foo.Baz.type. I am not sure if it's written anywhere explicitly, but for that to work (without a special treatment to enums) is when 2 different vals are always treated as different .types, no matter how they were created. Meanwhile objects do create separate non-anonymous classes

... so while I cannot point to a specific place in the spec, with the way enum works and assuming that language is consistent, 2 different vals have to be always treated as 2 different types (valName.type), creating 2 different path-dependent types inside of them. If these types are non-abstract, you could prove something about them (e.g. their actual type and from that if they are =:=), since they are abstract, compiler has to reject =:= since the inside of val is an event horizon, and cannot be looked at by the compiler.

Well, regarding 2nd question, =:= isn't a special feature at all: it's an implicit conversion provided when at the callsite compiler can prove that 2 types are equal. To generate v1.S1 =:= v2.S1 evidence out of v1.type =:= v1.type evidence I think one would need a transparent inline def macro checking existence of evidence for the paths root, and equality of both paths. It's something that is missing in Scala for years.

hmm, perhaps it shouldn't be called =:= anymore (which is just <:< in both ways), some uncanny macro will be required

Depends, if it's going to be v1.type =:= v2.type -> v1.foo.bar.baz =:= v2.foo.bar.baz, then it's going to be a series of nested Select trees, one only have to check that each Select is the same until it get to the root Ident - for that indent if there are differences, one needs implicit evidence v1.type =:= v2.type. When there would be different selects inside, which should have the same types, or type aliases that should resolve to the same types, etc it gets hairy. I guess it could be recursive replacing of one symbol with another, dealiases and queries to type system. Non trivial.

Actually I found is this post by Dmytro Mitin https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73832836/scala-3-dealing-with-path-dependent-types?rq=2 which explains where scala spec defines path-dependent equivalence and where it explicitly forbids what you ask for.

I read it long time ago but forgot, should have suspected compulsive widening immediately lol
